# How to build a ResourceManager in libGDX with AssetManager

Tags: libgdx, android-assets

I want use non static AssetManager In my android game? I have many levels. How should I use AssetManager? I should create for every level a separate AssetManager? Because if I create one AssetManager, it will load all textures, etc,  in first screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create one AssetManager in your main class which load all assets at the startup of the application. Then for each level you should create a different screen or use one screen, depending on your game. Then you pass a reference of the AssetManager to every new screen instance you create (for the screen to access it's assets).

**For example:**

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Game {

private GameScreen gameScreen;  // the game screen

private AssetManager assetManager;  // for loading all assets

public void create(){
    assetManager = new AssetManager();
    assetManager.load("assets/data/yourSkin", Skin.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();  // load assets (not asynchron for this example)
    setGameScreen();
}

public void setGameScreen(){
    setScreen(new GameScreen(this));
}

public void dispose() {
    assetManager.dispose();   // disposes all assets when the game exits
}

// so that screens can get the assetManager from the main class
public AssetManager getAssetManager() { return assetManager; }
}
```

GameScreen.java

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private Main mainClass;
private AssetManager assetManager;

private Skin skin;    // holds fonts, button style, ...


public GameScreen(Main mc) {

    // init
    this.mainClass = mc;
    assetManager = mc.getAssetManager();


    // load skin
    skin = assetManager.get("assets/data/skin", Skin.class);

    // make GUI...
}


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // draw
}
}
```